# Get modified date from Windows indexing search

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, search, indexing

I'm wondering it it is possible to retrieve the file modified date from a windows indexing search.

I'm getting the name of the file with:

```
objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemName")
```

And I'm not sure how to check all the properties or fields available in `objRecordset` but I've found googling this ones:

> SYSTEM.ITEMNAME
>
> SYSTEM.ITEMURL
>
> SYSTEM.FILEEXTENSION
>
> SYSTEM.FILENAME
>
> SYSTEM.FILEATTRIBUTES
>
> SYSTEM.FILEOWNER
>
> SYSTEM.ITEMTYPE
>
> SYSTEM.ITEMTYPETEXT
>
> SYSTEM.KINDTEXT
>
> SYSTEM.KIND
>
> SYSTEM.MIMETYPE
>
> SYSTEM.SIZE

As you can see there's nothing related with the date of the file but I find it difficult to believe this is not somewhere accessible.

This is the `vbs` script I'm using right now:

```
'To run this snippet, save it to a file and run it using cscript.exe from a command line. 
'Running the .vbs file with Windows Script Host may cause dialog boxes to open for each item returned from the index.

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT System.ItemName FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/folderIndexed' AND CONTAINS('INSULATING') ORDER BY System.ItemName DESC", objConnection

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemName")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: System.DateModified?

Comment: MMmm nop. It doesn't exist.

Comment: I assure you it does exist on my win7 64-bit

Comment: Trying to print it with `Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.DateModified")` gives me this error: `ADOB.Fields: Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal`

Comment: You added it in SELECT also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

objConnection.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows';"

objRecordSet.Open "SELECT System.ItemName, System.DateModified FROM SYSTEMINDEX WHERE DIRECTORY='file:C:/usr'", objConnection

Do Until objRecordset.EOF
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.ItemName")
    Wscript.Echo objRecordset.Fields.Item("System.DateModified")
    objRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
```

Produces this output:

```
README.txt
31.1.2014 17:20:14
bin
29.10.2012 14:09:02
share
29.10.2012 14:09:01
docs
29.10.2012 14:09:02
etc
29.10.2012 14:09:02
```

This list might help also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah ok, I was forgetting to add it on the query :). Thanks!

Comment: Just one short question. Is there anyway of returning it as an array with the date as the index of it?

Comment: that is beyond my knowledge, perhaps you should ask on StackOverflow